# How do OR statements affect multicolumn indexes in Postgres query

Tags: sql, activerecord, indexing

I'm currently querying my customers table in a postgres database when a user signs up (or makes an order as a guest) to see if we have any old records possibly matching the "new" user. 
Users also have the option of changing their names. When they do, we change their primary name but keep their old name in alt_fname and alt_lname fields. As a result our where clause (in ActiveRecord) is

`Customer.where(["(fname = :fname OR alt_fname = :fname) AND (lname = :lname OR alt_lname = :lname)", {fname: first_name, lname: last_name}])`

To speed things up I'd like to add some multi-column indexes (for example  on fname, lname),  but I don't know if they'll even be used given that the query isn't a straightforward AND statement, but two OR's joined by an AND.

Comment: `OR`s pretty much kill the use of indexes.

Comment: @GordonLinoff is this also true on postgress? https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/indexes-bitmap-scans.html

Answer (score 0):

@GordonLinoff is generally right.

Having said that try adding 2 sorted indices lname, user_id and alt_lname, user_id. I don't know what postgres' optimizer does but many will try retrieving via index and possibly switch to sequential if the match ratio is not good. If your cardinality is large then indexes will help.

If speed isn't improved try a UNION of two queries one with lname and one with alt_lname and return user_id. As it's not a union ALL there will still be a sort but that should only happen on the result set and not the whole table.